# Search Button Broken on Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, search

First off, I am not a developer. We don't have a dedicated developer for our Magento website. A few days ago my boss asked me to fix an error on the website. What is happening is the search button doesn't work. I try to click it and nothing happens. When I go into Inspect Element, there is an error in the console. It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" in prototype.js:5557.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix it. Which to be honest isn't a lot. I've reindexed files, cleared the cache, updated Magento, and made sure the button is located where its supposed to be. I've made sure products are searchable within Magento and I have made sure the search type is set to like/fulltext. I think its probably an error in the code, but I have no idea what to edit or where. I am going mad trying to figure this out.

The link to the store is: http://store.excitementvideo.net/ But please keep in mind it is NSFW.

Thank you

Update: I've been told its a form error? Here is my form.mini.phtml file

```html
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
       <form> <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text" /></form>
        <form><button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button></form>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, i noticed your store has a maintenance flag, you must delete the file 'maintenance.flag' in the root of your magento install. Once you do this i can investigate your issue further (if its still there)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the javascript has slight bug with the string part.

try changing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>');
    searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
//]]>
</script>
```

to

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__("Search entire store here...") ?>');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $this->helper("catalogsearch")->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried the edit you suggested, and then cleared the cache and reindexed. It doesn't appear to have worked. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: If you have installed some new modules lately, I suggest on trying to disable the newest one and check if the search works then. I've had before different modules which conflicted with each other. Sometimes there has been multiple jQuery versions and so on. The prototype shouldn't be crashing in itself, even though the error code points to it.